# Show hours with fullCalendar jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I've read documentation http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/agenda/axisFormat/ to display hours in week view. My code is:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    axisFormat:'h(:mm)tt',
    ...
});
```

But I still see basic calendar =(.

---

I didn't see hous due to the header. My header was:

```
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
```

ando now is:

```
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,basicDay'
        },
```

And I can see hous

Answer (score 1):

Just try this it would work, its working for me just fine.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today prevYear',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'nextYear month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        axisFormat: 'H(:mm)',/*whatever format you want for axis */
        timeFormat: {
            agenda: 'H:mm{ - H:mm}'/*time format to be shown on event*/
        },

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The axisFormat option only dictates how it should be displayed in that agenda view, to actually change the view you need to use the [changeView](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/changeView/) method

For example to change the view

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaWeek')
```

Comment: You should still pass in the `axisFormat` when initializing the calendar, it will just only appear when the calendar is in the *agendaWeek* view.

Answer (score 0):

U can use 'agendaWeekDay' to header > right parameter for show time

```
    header: {
            right: 'agendaWeekDay'
        },
```